# recvfrom icmp packet without ip header

Tags: sockets, icmp, recvfrom

I am trying to get an ICMP packet using the `recvfrom()` function. The function receives a packet including the IP header, I only need the ICMP portion.

Is it possible to somehow configure the socket so that `recvfrom()` receives only an ICMP packet through it, without the IP header?

I create socket like this:

```c
int sock_fd;
if ((sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP)) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    return ERROR;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I got an answer that this is impossible. So, if I make the buffer large, since the length of the IP header can be different, will `recvfrom()` write only one packet to the buffer, or can it be that the beginning of the next packet will be written to the end of the buffer?

Comment: No. It is not...

Comment: understandable, thanks.

Comment: Per the [raw()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html) documentation: "*The IPv4 layer generates an IP header when sending a packet unless the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option is enabled on the socket. When it is enabled, the packet must contain an IP header.  **For receiving, the IP header is always included in the packet.***"

Comment: thank you, Could it be that recvfrom() will write a packet to the buffer, and part of the next packet, if the buffer size is too large?